# Permission Denial accessing picture URI on app restart

Tags: android, permissions, android-contentresolver

It wouldn't be android programming without the occasional hair-pulling experience...

Using emulator at the moment...

This evidently is a new feature:

```
Permission Denial: opening provider com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider.impl.MediaContentProvider from ProcessRecord{6ebfe9e 22355:xxx/u0a140} (pid=22355, uid=10140) that is not exported from UID 10068
```

Access to EXTERNAL_STORAGE has been granted in all cases.

Scenario:

1. User selects a picture (using ACTION_GET_CONTENT) and activity
   result is good and picture is displayed within my app context.
2. URI to picture is saved in app DB.
3. App is restarted.
4. Attempt to access ***same*** URI and get the above Permission Denial
   exception.

Then tried `takePersistableUriPermission` on original picture selection activity result and that throws an exception indicating there are no persistable permissions.

EDIT: Ok, I've implemented the accepted answer (but just using OPEN_DOCUMENT) and no longer attempt to project the resultant URI into a media path.  So in an act of repentance, I state again:

> I will never attempt to translate a URI into a Media Store path.

(Even though GET_CONTENT and projecting once worked - OK I can't help myself.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed.

Uries obtained with ACTION_GET_CONTENT are only valid as long as your app runs.

If you want to persist the uri start with ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE and then in onActivityResult make the obtained permissions persistent.

Have a look at takePersistabkeUriPermission().

(Or something like that).

You do not need external storage permissions and such.

Comment: Well, this has lead to next problem as I attempt to take URI and use a contentresolver query to project the URI into a Media.DATA path so I can construct a File object to render it.  So I wonder if I don't need to do that part any longer?

Comment: Very very very wrong! Do away with that all. You should take the permissions and then save data.getData().toString() to your db. That is the obtained content scheme. You have nothing to do with the File class or a file system path.

Comment: @greenapps Understood - android has punished me appropriately.  It is difficult maintaining a 4 year old android app.  Thanks all - I believe it is working with the ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT and not projecting the URI - just use it as is.